# How can I change a student's historical grade level based on previous years?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I'm working with a pandas data frame with historical student data. I have a column with student assessment scores (from previous academic years), a column with the calendar year the score was from, and a column with the students' current (2020-2021) grade level. I'm looking to make a column that has the student's grade level at the time of the assessment. The problem is, not all student grade levels are numeric. The Grade levels I have in order are [PS, TK, K, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]. I can write a bunch of conditional 'if' statements, but I'm curious if there's a quicker way.

Sample of what I have:

```
   Student Score  Assessment Date   Current Grade Level
0  A              2017-2018         1    
1  B              2018-2019         1    
2  C              2019-2020         1    
3  B              2020-2021         1
```

Sample Expected Output:

```
   Student Score  Assessment Date   Current Grade Level   Assessment Grade Level
0  A              2017-2018         1                     PS
1  B              2018-2019         1                     TK
2  C              2019-2020         1                     K
3  B              2020-2021         1                     1
```

Comment: We are curious for a sample of data in text form. And the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with an `ordered` [CategoricalDtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalDtype.html):

```
cat_type = pd.CategoricalDtype(["PS", "TK", "K", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                               ordered=True)
df['Current Grade Level'] = df['Current Grade Level'].astype(cat_type)
```

Get right value from `Assessment Date`:

```
df['Assessment Date'].str.split('-').str[-1].astype(int)
```

```
0    2018
1    2019
2    2020
3    2021
Name: Assessment Date, dtype: int32
```

Then calculate the offset based on the year:

```
year = 2021  # or to get current year pd.Timestamp.now().year
s = year - df['Assessment Date'].str.split('-').str[-1].astype(int)
```

`s`:

```
0    3
1    2
2    1
3    0
Name: Assessment Date, dtype: int32
```

Then update the categories based on that offset and convert back to categorical [pd.Categorical.from_codes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.from_codes.html):

```
df['Assessment Grade Level'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(
    df['Current Grade Level'].cat.codes - s,
    categories=cat_type.categories,
    ordered=True
)
```

`df`:

```
  Student Score Assessment Date Current Grade Level Assessment Grade Level
0             A       2017-2018                   1                     PS
1             B       2018-2019                   1                     TK
2             C       2019-2020                   1                      K
3             B       2020-2021                   1                      1
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Student Score': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B'],
    'Assessment Date': ['2017-2018', '2018-2019', '2019-2020',
                        '2020-2021'],
    'Current Grade Level': [1, 1, 1, 1]
})

cat_type = pd.CategoricalDtype(["PS", "TK", "K", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                               ordered=True)
df['Current Grade Level'] = df['Current Grade Level'].astype(cat_type)

year = 2021
s = year - df['Assessment Date'].str.split('-').str[-1].astype(int)
df['Assessment Grade Level'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(
    df['Current Grade Level'].cat.codes - s,
    categories=cat_type.categories,
    ordered=True
)
print(df)
```

Comment: I knew there was something like this out there! Thank you! This is very helpful!